# Rails Devise broke on sqlite -> Mysql upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a rails 3.0.9 application that is using Devise for user authentication. It was previously using SQLite, but I changed my application's database to MySQL.

Upon switching to MySQL, the user registration function of Devise stopped working. I'm not getting an error in the rails log. When a new user tries to register, they are simply routed back to the signup page after clicking 'Submit.'

Are there any DB references in the Devise config files that I need to change in order to having Devise play nicely with MySQL?

I should also not that user login / logout is working correctly under MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I had added a before_save :default_values filter on my user model. I originally did this to set default values for certain attributes on the model level. I instead ran a migration setting defaults at the DB level, deleted the before_save call from the model, and everything worked fine.

Silly mistake. Hopefully this helps someone else.